# Import data file into excel or access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an excel file which I've been supplied a layout for with the name, length, start and end positions of each field for a data file.  Any ideas on an any easy way to use this layout file to import the data file into its respective fields in access or excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.ini ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx